# DLL interface between sw

Tags: c++, dll

I have experience with C# and C/C++, but I never worked with DLLs so I am trying to figure out how it works.

I need to integrate a native dll API interface between third part software and my future little sw that is going to substitute the original.

Specs from third part are limited and describe a prototype like:

```
Error GetInfo([in/out]LPTSTR errorInfo, [in]DWORD errorBufferLength);
```

I created a dll project with CodeBlocks and MINGW, my target now is to receive a initial feedback, so in dll file .cpp I wrote this code:

```
DLL_EXPORT TCHAR x[5];

Error DLL_EXPORT GetInfo(LPTSTR errorInfo, DWORD errorBufferLength)
{
    x = TEXT("test");

    errorInfo = x;
    errorBufferLength = sizeof(TCHAR*5);

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

and in main.h there is:

```
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT TCHAR x[];

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
Error DLL_EXPORT GetInfo(LPTSTR errorInfo, DWORD ErrorBufferLength);

}
```

when I look at the third part log in the errorInfo string I found "corrupted" string with ASCII character like I am pointing at the wrong memory position or the format is not correct. Using the original dll the output is correct.
I tried different and different forms to assign the right values at the LPTSTR pointer and DWORD, but I am sure I am missing something about the theory.

Do you have any suggestion ? Sorry to my "be a beginner"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*errorInfo* is a pointer the caller of *GetInfo()* provides. You cannot overwrite it.
Currently, nothing is copied to the caller's buffer.

So you will need to use one of the string-copy functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncpy-strncpy-l-wcsncpy-wcsncpy-l-mbsncpy-mbsncpy-l?view=vs-2019

I assume *errorBufferLength* contains the size of the buffer, provided by the caller. So you'll need to limit the copy to it.

e.g.:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

const TCHAR g_const_text[] = _T("Hello World!");

void getString(LP s, size_t bufSize)
{
    _tcsncpy_s(s, bufSize, g_const_text, _tcslen(g_const_text));
}

int main()
{
    TCHAR t[100];
    getString(t, 100);
    MessageBox(NULL, t, _T("test"), MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for info. About errorInfo() name, I named it in that way here to simplify, in the code the name is different. I just want to add: LPTSTR is a pointer, should I use strcpy functions anyway ?

Comment: You should yoused the TCHAR variant of the strcpy functions. e.g. _tcsncpy_s
I added an example in my answer above.

Comment: many thanks, about the memory allocation for the variable, is it correct to put it in the dll .cpp file ? The variable is going to be shared between the two different software ?

Comment: if it is also a const in your case, you could pull it into the function. It does not need the DLL_EXPORT keyword, since it is not shared with the user of the DLL.

Comment: btw.: you should wrap the #ifdef __cplusplus also around the closing curly braces.

Comment: _tcsncpy_s is not present in tchar.h library in my Mingw-gcc version, i looked also in the tchar.h file; which function do you recommend ? I tried _tcsncpy but the result is the same.

Comment: Actually I tested with Visual Studio. I wasn't aware the mingw variant of tchar.h doesn't support all functions.
What *cpy functions are contained in your mingw tchar.h? You'll have to select one. 
_tcsncpy_s has the advantage, that it does not overrun the caller's buffer, if it is too small. So if you use another string-copy function you should compare that the caller's buffer (in number of chars)is >

Comment: ... than the number of chars to copy.

Comment: I am trying my best, I switched (came back to) Visual Studio and I created a sample similar to your. I also tried to add a very simply file output to use as debug but it doesn't respond well to my output, no file created. Is it possible that if original dll and sw were made in VS2008 and MFC I need to use the same enviroment to obtain good result ? Also if third part sw is made in Java. DLL must written in the same exactly enviroment to avoid incompatibility ?

Comment: opening dll file with the text editor I can find reference to visual c 90 that should be 2008

Comment: At the end, a big issue was made by bit "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" that I should have set in VS configuration set for the project. Thanks @irqmask for your assistance, your help was very useful for my understanding process !